# Reading multiple parameters from message body

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Can I read more than one parameter from message body?

Example :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

Comment: No, you bind the whole body of an HTTP message to a parameter. However, a single parameter can be a complex object!!

Answer (score 5):

No.

So if you have several things you want to send in the body and are sending them as json, then in your browser post you can post something like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Callum"
}
```

In your C#, you create an object that represents this data:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Person person) { ... }
```

The model binder will take care of doing the conversion from JSON to C#

---

You can however read both query parameters and body into a single action, using `[FromUrl]` or `[FromBody]` depending on what version of ASP.NET you're using

Take a look at this http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing and generally around the http://www.asp.net/mvc